# Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView, the debugger shows it is inside the bounds

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I get the error `Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView` for the following code

```
let data = [...] // some array of Int16
let buf = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
let dataView = new DataView(buf);

data.forEach((b, i) => {
   dataView.setInt16(i, b);
});
```

Here is the debug view in Chrome

[image]

You can see that `i` is `47999` and the buffer size of my `DataView` is `48000`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try `const buf = new ArrayBuffer(16);` as it is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setInt16 in the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because an Int16Array has a 2 bytes per element. So its `.length` will be twice smaller than its buffer's actual size, use its `.byteLength` instead to create a new ArrayBuffer of the same size.
Also, setting an int16 will actually set two bytes at a time.

So at some point, your loop will try to set a byte that doesn't exist, and it will throw that error.

But that's not all with your code. Since `forEach()`'s iteration value `i` is based on the `.length` value of the TypedArray, you also need to multiply it by the TypedArray's bytes per element to set a correct offset in `DataView.setInt16`.

```js
const data = new Int16Array( [ 0xFFFF, 0xFF00, 0x00FF, 0x000 ] );

console.log( "length:", data.length );
console.log( "byteLength:", data.byteLength );

const buf = new ArrayBuffer(data.byteLength);
const dataView = new DataView(buf);

data.forEach( (b, i) => {
  dataView.setInt16( i * data.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, b );
} );
console.log( new Int16Array( buf ) );
// -1, 255, -256, 0
```

Now, I'm not sure what you were wanting to do with this snippet, but to make a copy of your TypedArray, then you'd have to check for the endianness of the computer and then use the third parameter of `DataView.setInt16( byteOffset, value, littleEndian )`, but you could also simply do:

```js
const data = new Int16Array( [ 0xFFFF, 0xFF00, 0x00FF, 0x000 ] );
const buf = data.buffer.slice();

// ensure they are not the same ArrayBuffer
data.fill( 0 );
console.log( "data: ", data ); // 0, 0, 0 ,0
console.log( "copy:", new Int16Array( buf ) );
// -1, 256, 255, 0
```

If you wanted to swap from little endian to big endian, then you could also make it way faster than using a DataView by first checking the computer's endianness and swapping the values using `.map` if necessary.

```js
const data = new Int16Array( [ 0xFFFF, 0xFF00, 0x00FF, 0x000 ] );
// check for the computer's endianness
const is_little_endian = new Uint8Array( new Uint32Array( [ 0x12345678 ] ).buffer )[ 0 ] === 0x78;
console.log( is_little_endian );

const buf = is_little_endian ?
  data.map( (val) => (val<<8) | (val>>8) & 0xFF ).buffer : data.buffer.slice();

// ensure they are not the same ArrayBuffer
data.fill( 0 );
console.log( "data: ", data ); // 0, 0, 0 ,0
console.log( "copy:", new Int16Array( buf ) );
// -1, 255, -256, 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear. I missed the point of the `byteLength`

Comment: You're welcome, I just noticed that I also missed one point in your code, did you omit the third param of `setInt16` on purpose so it's set as BigEndian? In this case the simple `slice()` snippet won't do the same.

Comment: Actually this is kind of an X,Y problem. I ended up with your answer on the latter parts.